# pm2 - Restart on file save (pm2 logs)

Tags: pm2

I am using pm2 on a Debian machine to keep a few scripts alive.

I initially started the scripts individually but then I've realised a script change would restart all processes (which I keep an eye on with pm2 logs) so I moved everything into a json file as follows:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "tele-robot",
      "script": "./tele-robot.js",
      "watch": true,     
      "ignore_watch" : ["./temp"]
    },
    {
      "name": "hello",
      "script": "./hello.js",
      "watch": true,     
      "ignore_watch" : ["./temp"]
    }
  ]
}
```

How should I configure my file in order to only restart, or reload, a service, after a file has been modified?

I need these services running and I would like to avoid exiting pm2 logs, reload, and pm2 logs again, after every change.

All the processes have been started successfully with the watch enabled:

[image]

Comment: when you do watch enable, it actually watches for all the files, if any change occures, it restarts that particular app only, and during watch, it ignores if you have specified any file in ignore watch

Comment: So you're saying that if I remove the ignore_watch for say tele-robot.js, when I modify that file pm2 logs will pick up the change and restart that process?

Comment: i'm not sure what do you mean  by `pm2 logs` here. but yeah, it will restart the process.